# tiddlywiki on OSX

Tags: macos, safari, tiddlywiki

I can't seem to find an option to work with Tiddlywiki on OSX (recently upgraded to Maverick). Chrome, my main browser, is out of the question because java7 doesn't support 32 bit chrome. On either Firefox or Safari, the behavior is the same: I open the wiki, change something and press save: it says "right click here to download the main wiki file". No other error message is given. But the actual file is NOT saved.

ps. I've tried with latest tiddlywiki download with the same result.

Comment: I was able to get Tiddlywiki 5 with nodejs working on Mavericks, mostly following the standard instructions from the repo. Migration between old-tw and tw5 isn't done yet.

Comment: Possibly related:  http://superuser.com/questions/539015/how-do-i-add-a-file-to-firefoxs-hidden-list-of-trusted-files